# EXCEL - Using SWITCH for 3 combinations from different sources

Tags: excel

I have the situation as follows:

I would like to automatize the calendar of the timesheet. I am fine with the months, days and WEEKDAY function, although the biggest challenge is to make two columns occurring "inside" the weekend. They sum up the whole week and include both % as well as the Cost column.

[image]

When I change the month, these coumns stay in the same place whereas I would like to have them movable as well as the other WEEKDAYS do. They should be always between the Saturday and Sunday.

I found the SWITCH function to be quite useful along with nested IF and IFS

https://www.bcti.com/2017/02/06/excel-ifs-and-switch-function-say-goodbye-to-nested-ifs-and-vlookups-on-small-tables/

https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/nested-if-statements-ifs-switch/

Basically the functions aren't complicated, although I have no option to include the value of other cell.
Assuming, that I have the % value for cell T3 (T2=Wk50 as above) I would like to have the condition, which will pick up also the value of "Cost" for the same cell as well as the calendar value of this cell (i.e. 9/12/23).
For this reason I've prepared soe code, which doesn't work well enough.
=SWITCH(WEEKDAY(S3,2),7,"Cost",WEEKDAY(S3,2),6,"%",S3).

Is there any way to have the flexibility such as this?

UPDATE:
After applying the following formula:

```
   =SWITCH(WEEKDAY(AI9,2),6,"%",7,"Cost",AJ9)
```

I have still the wrong order:

[image]

As weekend days are missing.

Comment: Keep `WEEKDAY(S3,2)` for the first parameter of `SWITCH()` function and then use it in this way `=SWITCH(WEEKDAY(S3,2),7,"Cost",6,"%",S3)` Read here the documentation **[MSFT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e)** --> `SWITCH()` states : _evaluates one value (called the expression) against a list of values, and returns the result corresponding to the first matching value. If there is no match, an optional default value may be returned._

Comment: It doesn't work. basically, the formula is correct and throws the 3 cases, although there is no offset, which I would need. Is there a way of combination the SWITCH function with the offset?

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots, please use **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** to show your input and expected output.

Comment: I can send you the whole file if you don't mind

Comment: You could post the link here, and kindly show the expected output by doing manually for few of them, two / three will be fine. Any cloud storage link, that will be helpful for me to follow

Comment: Yes, please see the link:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/t4lqke2z87qw9lu4smv03/Tracker-file.xlsx?rlkey=yj0flh36zw8y2av3khf2hwp2h&dl=0

Please go to sheet 2 and check the row 11 I am working on. Row 13 (marked yellow) shows values that should be applied in row 11 but they are different. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Ok, give me sometime, i will brb!

Comment: So the correction will be from `AP11` cell onwards or `AG11`? because i see you have applied the formula `AJ11` onwards.

Comment: Yes, as I want to have the order like this: Mon-Tue-Wed-Thu-Fri-Sat-%-Cost-Sun-Mon....
So without the decent formula I can have only:
Mon-Tue-Wed-Thu-Fri-%-Cost-Mon

Comment: So the pattern will be like : `Mon-Tue-Wed-Thurs-Fri-%-Cost-Sat-Sun-Mon-Tue-Wed-Thurs-Fri-%-Cost-etc`? sorry just want to be sure about it

Comment: No, the pattern must be:
Mon-Tue-Wed-Thu-Fri-Sat-%-Cost-Sun-Mon-Tue-Wed-Thu-Fri-Sat-%-Cost-Sun..